# File sizes ordered by date

Tags: filesystems, cygwin

If I had FSQL, I would write `select size from directory1 order by date`. But, I have a Windows and Cygwin. Windows Explorer can sort the items by date but it rounds the file sizes to much. So, I am looking for other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have Cygwin, you can do this in the shell of a Cygwin terminal (mintty).

```
cd directory1
ls -lt
```

`ls` will list the files in the current directory, directory1. The `-l` option will use the long form for display, which includes file sizes, and the `-t` option will sort according to modification time. Use

```
man ls
```

to find more details on these and other options.